# dom html ,get link audio from link

Tags: html

i have this link :

[link here](http://blogviet.com.vn/blog-radio/blog-radio-300-chin-muoi-ngay-cho-mai-mai-phan-2-/5306)

how can i get link audio in this link to play ?.

i just find some code but it is not link media .

```
<object width="99%" height="80" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="jwplayer"
                    name="jwplayer" data="http://media.nhacvietplus.com.vn/mediaplayer/playertest/player_test16.swf">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">                         
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=/upload/music/gaquay/blogradio300chinmuoingaychomaimaiphan2/fulltrack/blogradio300chinmuoingaychomaimaiphan2.mp3&amp;streamer=rtmp://123.29.67.163:1935/vod/_definst_/&amp;plugins=http://plugin.innity.net/jw/InnityAdsPlugin.swf&config=http://media.nhacvietplus.com.vn/mediaplayer/iap_config.xml&amp;autostart=true&stretching=exactfit">
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join param value 'flashvars' from object and http://media.nhacvietplus.com.vn/

As a result you will have a link like this: 
http://media.nhacvietplus.com.vn/upload/music/gaquay/blogradio300chinmuoingaychomaimaiphan2/fulltrack/blogradio300chinmuoingaychomaimaiphan2.mp3

Is it what you want?

Comment: wao why you can get .it is exactly i want ?